# Hosting a web service on port 22... Is that possible? frowned upon?

Tags: php, ssh, proxy, http, port

I am trying to resolve a client's problem and I had an (bad?) idea...

**The problem :**

Client has two web servers running behind his wan router. (physical servers in his building)

Each server hosts a different web service and merging down the two servers is not an option.

The router forwards requests on port 80 to server A (and that can't change) and requests on port 90 to server B.

(**[[EDIT]]** : Right now server B is interrogated directly from the web browser via the client's IP and port 90... This is wrooooong...)

I need to interrogate server B via a PHP (proxy) script from a 1and1 mutualized server.

The hosting company (1and1) has a firewall that prevent developers from sending requests on other ports than 21, 22 and 80.

**The idea :**

Changing my client's router's port forwarding rules so that server B is accessible via port 22, and sending requests via php on port 22.

**The question :**

Is it a terrible practice to use port 22 for http requests?

Is there a simple way to test my PHP proxy script in the first place by sending an http request to a (any) server's port 22?

Comment: Why downvote? I'm crying now...

Comment: "The router forwards ... requests on port 90 to server B" "The hosting company ... prevent developers from sending requests on other ports than 21, 22 and 80." So how do the requests to port 90 make it anywhere at all, if only ports 21, 22 and 80 are allowed through? (And no, not my downvote.)

Comment: Hmmm... I wanna change the config "so that server B is accessible via port 22"
See edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Officially port 22 is reserved for secure shell access (ssh/sftp). It is good practice to follow the standards set out by the IANA, but so long as you don't require those services there isn't a problem with running your HTTP port forwarding against 22. It will work (I have done this before due to similar reasons).

> "The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) is responsible for
>   maintaining the official assignments of port numbers for specific
>   uses. However, many unofficial uses of both well-known and registered
>   port numbers occur in practice." -  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

SvW is right though, a reverse proxy on the LAN would be a good solution and save headaches in the future.

[edit]

More information on setting up a reverse proxy can be found here:
http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/06/multiple-web-servers-over-a-single-ip-using-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy/

This is also a really good post on stack overflow about forward and reverse proxy servers, listing resources at the end:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224664/difference-between-proxy-server-and-reverse-proxy-server

Answer (score 7):

- Change the hosting provider (or hosting plan). If you have a legitimate need to access another port, a hosting company should not restrict you.
- Set up a reverse proxy inside your LAN that maps request to the respective servers.

Comment: So you're saying my idea is a terrible one...? ;-)

Comment: The reverse proxy is the second best solution. This way, all of the servers on the internal network can be publicly reached by port 80. The best solution is IPv6 so you don't have this problem at all.

Comment: Well, I cannot change the hosting provider. I am not a sysadmin, I'm a (web/android)developper. I have no idea how IPv6 would solve the problem, nor how to setup a reverse proxy (on what parameter does it base itself to route packets to one or the other server?)
Any explanation/links/... would be more than welcome... Thanks in advance and thanks a lot!

Comment: If your client's choice of web hosting provider prevents you from doing something which you have a legitimate need for in the course of your interactions with the client, you certainly can (and probably should) suggest that the client changes to a different web host. You can even compile a short list of possible alternatives, along with the cost of each per month (or whatever). Of course in the end it's the client's choice, but your job is to *solve problems for the client*, and if that means making some changes then by all means you should suggest they make those changes.

Comment: +1 for reverse proxy, if you can not get more then 1 public IP this is the way to go. have a look at nginx if you want to get something thats easy to configure (even if your a windows man, because TMG is ... meh)

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a redirect page for one (or both) of the sites using host header recognition. So all port 80 traffic goes to one box and is re-routed from there. Similar to a reverse proxy but perhaps easier to set up (especially if you're using IIS).